# change unordered data in python as ordered dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

i have given txt file in following format

```
a: 40     b: 20    c: 20     d: 00 23 4f 40 5f
a: 20     b: 30    c: 50     d: 23 45 21 54 43
a: 20     b: 30    c: 50     d: 23 45 21 
a: 20     b: 30    c: 50     d:
```

i used read_csv() function to read the fiven file. However i am struggling with make this type of format as dataframe in order to analyze.

the final dataframe i want is

```
a    b    c    d_1   d_2   d_3   d_4   d_5
40   20   20   00    23    4f    40    5f
20   30   50   23    45    21    54    43
20   30   50   23    45    21
20   30   50
```

I Have tried split function using ' ' as divisor. However since there is data that are not written it causes disorder.

Is there another way to make this type of data as data frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be hard if you try to find a way to load it with read_csv(). I think it would be better if you clean your data before loading it into a data frame.

```
def check_index(list, index):
    return "" if index > (len(list)-1) else list[index].rstrip()

a, b, c, d1 ,d2, d3, d4, d5 = [] , [] ,[] , [],[] , [] ,[] , []
with open('./text.txt') as file:
    for line in file.readlines():
        values = list(compo.split(': ')[1] for compo in line.split('    ')) # 4 space split according to your sample data
        a.append(values[0])
        b.append(values[1])
        c.append(values[2])
        d_values = values[3].split(' ')
        d1.append(check_index(d_values,0))
        d2.append(check_index(d_values,1))
        d3.append(check_index(d_values,2))
        d4.append(check_index(d_values,3))
        d5.append(check_index(d_values,4))

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(a, b, c, d1 ,d2, d3, d4, d5)), columns = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd1', 'd2', 'd3', 'd4', 'd5'])
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have a question does "# 4 space split according to your sample data" comment mean that in a single row each data has 4 space between them? if it's the case what should i do if the space between them are different?

Comment: @mingeuns yes correct. If there are different spaces between them, you need to find a unique delimiter to split it such as using ":" instead of "    ".

Answer (score 0):

start with:

```
s = """a: 40     b: 20    c: 20     d: 00 23 4f 40 5f
a: 20     b: 30    c: 50     d: 23 45 21 54 43
a: 20     b: 30    c: 50     d: 23 45 21 
a: 20     b: 30    c: 50     d: """
```

Split into rows:

```
rows = s.split("\n")

rows
['a: 40     b: 20    c: 20     d: 00 23 4f 40 5f', 'a: 20     b: 30    c: 50     d: 23 45 21 54 43', 'a: 20     b: 30    c: 50     d: 23 45 21 ', 'a: 20     b: 30    c: 50     d: ']
```

Split row into columns:

```
cols = row.split("    ")

cols
['a: 40', ' b: 20', 'c: 20', ' d: 00 23 4f 40 5f']
```

Split a cell into the column letter and values:

```
cell = cols[-1]
letter, values = cell.split(":")
letter
' d'
values
' 00 23 4f 40 5f'
```

convert letter and values into a dictionary:

```
new_col = {f"{letter}_{i}": v for i, v in enumerate(values.strip(" ").split(" "))}
new_col
{' d_0': '00', ' d_1': '23', ' d_2': '4f', ' d_3': '40', ' d_4': '5f'}
```

Merge the dictionaries back together:

```
def merge_dicts(list_of_dicts: List[Dict[str, str]]):
    new_d = {}
    for d in list_of_dicts:
        new_d.update(d)
    return new_d

rows = [merge_dicts(row) for row in cells]

rows
[{'a_0': '40', 'b_0': '20', 'c_0': '20', 'd_0': '00', 'd_1': '23', 'd_2': '4f', 'd_3': '40', 'd_4': '5f'}, {'a_0': '20', 'b_0': '30', 'c_0': '50', 'd_0': '23', 'd_1': '45', 'd_2': '21', 'd_3': '54', 'd_4': '43'}, {'a_0': '20', 'b_0': '30', 'c_0': '50', 'd_0': '23', 'd_1': '45', 'd_2': '21'}, {'a_0': '20', 'b_0': '30', 'c_0': '50', 'd_0': ''}]
```

Convert to a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(rows)

  a_0 b_0 c_0 d_0  d_1  d_2  d_3  d_4
0  40  20  20  00   23   4f   40   5f
1  20  30  50  23   45   21   54   43
2  20  30  50  23   45   21  NaN  NaN
3  20  30  50      NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

full code:

```
from typing import List, Dict
import pandas as pd

s = """a: 40     b: 20    c: 20     d: 00 23 4f 40 5f
a: 20     b: 30    c: 50     d: 23 45 21 54 43
a: 20     b: 30    c: 50     d: 23 45 21 
a: 20     b: 30    c: 50     d: """

def cell_to_dict(cell: str):
    letter, values = cell.split(":")
    letter = letter.strip(" ")
    values = values.strip(" ")
    d = {f"{letter}_{i}": v for i, v in enumerate(values.split(" "))}
    return d

def merge_dicts(list_of_dicts: List[Dict[str, str]]):
    new_d = {}
    for d in list_of_dicts:
        new_d.update(d)
    return new_d

def parse_file(s: str):
    rows = s.split("\n")
    cols = [row.split("    ") for row in rows]
    cells = [[cell_to_dict(cell) for cell in col] for col in cols]
    rows = [merge_dicts(row) for row in cells]
    df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
    return df


print(parse_file(s))
```

Its not quite there as cell `["d_0"][3]` is `''` rather than `NaN`, and the names of the columns are slightly different, but its pretty close

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new list of your columns in the desired order, then use df = df[cols] to rearrange the columns in this new order.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).